# splitting a matrix row-wise and and finding a linear regression coeff

Tags: matlab, matrix, split

```
A= [1 1
    2 2
    3 3
    . .
    . .
    . . 
    N N]
```

I have an `[N,2]` matrix  and I need to split it row-wise into some number of `[N/4,2]` submatrices.  Then for each submatrix I need to find linear regression where the first column of each submatrix is my x data and the second column is my y data. The output should be a struct with fields a,b,c,d.... and values of linear regression for each submatrix

First I tried splitting the matrix with `mat2cell` where `k = length(N)/4` and `mat = mat2cell(A, [k k k k], [1 1])`.

Next I tried converting mat into struct with `out = cell2struct(mat,fields,1)` where `fields = {'col1','col2'}` and use

```
new = structfun(@(x)polyfit(x.col1, x.col2,1), out,'UniformOutput', false)
```

But I get the error:

```
Inputs to STRUCTFUN must be scalar structures.
```

Does anyone know how to do it? Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforawrd way (and probably the fastest) to do this is with a good old `for` loop:

```
A = [1:64;1:64]'; % Demo data
m = 4;
N = size(A,1);
k = N/m;          % Assumes that length is evenly divisible by 4

c = zeros(m,2);   % Coefficients
for i = 1:m
    c(i,:) = polyfit(A((i-1)*k+1:i*k,1),A(i-1)*k+1:i*k,2),1);
end
```

Or rather than using `cell2struct` and `structfun` you can use [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html):

```
A = [1:64;1:64]'; % Demo data
m = 4;
N = size(A,1);
k = N/m;          % Assumes that length is evenly divisible by 4

c = cellfun(@(x)polyfit(x(:,1),x(:,2),1).',mat2cell(A,k+zeros(1,m),2),'UniformOutput',false)
```

or alternatively

```
Ac = mat2cell(A,k+zeros(1,m),[1 1])
c = cellfun(@(x1,x2)polyfit(x1,x2,1).',Ac(:,1),Ac(:,2),'UniformOutput',false)
```

You can convert the output of `cellfun` to a matrix with:

```
c = [c{:}].'
```

As for why you're getting the error, your variable `out` is a 4-by-1 struct array (array of structures) rather than a simple (scalar) structure of arrays. The documentation for `structfun` points out this requirement in the description of the short function: "Apply function to each field of scalar structure." This [video from The MathWorks](http://blogs.mathworks.com/videos/2008/04/22/matlab-basics-array-of-structures-vs-structures-of-arrays/) tries to explain the difference.